# I expect infinite loop,but not,why？

Tags: java, volatile

code like this

for test two case

one is have volatile keywords ,can stop

other is without volatile,the thread infinite loop

```
public class VolatileTest extends Thread {

    public boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        VolatileTest volatileTest = new VolatileTest();
        volatileTest.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        volatileTest.flag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!flag) {
            System.out.println("=====>");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @WJS tks. and I know what is volatile.  I coding for test without volatile. my program didn't infinite loop. it can stop

Comment: @WJS Maybe jvm dosomthing ?

Comment: @WJS My English is very poor ,Do u konw what I'm talking about

Comment: @WJS No, I don't use volalite. so the thread maybe use the "flag" mermory copy.

Comment: You changed the flag value to true inside the volatileTest object so insure the loop the condition equated to false due to the change and the while loop ended.

Comment: @CureMe I know I change the flag value ,but in multi thread,the flag value is cpu cache。

Comment: Nothing in the Java Memory Model prevents the thread from reading the updated value of your variable. It is just that threads of your program _are allowed_ to cache the value. If they decide not to cache but re-read the value at every access, that's fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  The problem is that you are calling a `synchronized` method inside your while loop.  Try it like this.  `Stopped` will never print unless you redeclare `flag` as `volatile`.

```
public class VolatileTest extends Thread {

    public boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        VolatileTest volatileTest = new VolatileTest();
        volatileTest.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        volatileTest.flag = true;
        System.out.println("flag is now " + flag);
         
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (!flag) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: On my laptop the above code kept running, even after setting flag to true.

Comment: More precisely, the problem is that a *synchronized* method was called inside the while loop, not just any method.  Thread-local values won't be updated until you hit a synchronized block/method.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong  Yeah.  Should have added that. I will make the change.  Regards!

Comment: @WJS look the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/51bdw.png .it stiil stopped

Comment: thank you very much @WJS.    I use gradle build...and I new a project without gradle it kept running.